# preprocess within cross-validation in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a question about data preprocess that need to be clarified. To my understanding, when we tune hyperparameters and estimate model performance via cross-validation, rather than preprocess the whole dataset, we need to do that within cross-validation. In other words, in cross-validation, we preprocess training folds, then use the same preprocess parameter to process test fold and make predictions.

In the example code below, when I specify the preProcess within caret::train, does it automatically do that? Really appreciate it if someone can clarify me on that.

From some online sources, some people preprocess the whole dataset (trainset) and then use the preprocess data to tune hyperparameters via cross-validation, it does not seems to be right....

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

control <- trainControl(method="cv", 
                        number=5,
                        preProcOptions = list(pcaComp=4))
grid=expand.grid(mtry=c(1,2,3))

model <- train(diabetes~., data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, method="rf", 
               preProcess=c("scale", "center", "pca"), 
               trControl=control,
               tuneGrid=grid)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your worries are on the right spot. So many ways to introduce positive bias.

According to Max Kuhn the creator of caret there is no data leakage when `preProcess` is specified in `train`:

> All pre-processing is applied on the resampled version of the data
>   (e.g. 90% in 10-fold CV) and then those calculations are applied to
>   the holdouts (the remaining 10%) with no re-calculation.

source: https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/335

Comment: Is this also true when using recipes with caret?

Comment: Sorry to dig this up @missuse. Imagine you want to predict new data with the model from the cv. Am I right assuming that `predict(model, newdata=df2)` would automatically preprocess the new supplied data?

Comment: @Björn B yes it will preprocess the new data prior doing the prediction.