# PCA within cross validation; however, only with a subset of variables

Tags: machine-learning, pca, cross-validation, r-caret

This question is very similar to [preprocess within cross-validation in caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295233/preprocess-within-cross-validation-in-caret); however, in a project that i'm working on I would only like to do PCA on three predictors out of 19 in my case. Here is the example from [preprocess within cross-validation in caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295233/preprocess-within-cross-validation-in-caret) and I'll use this data (`PimaIndiansDiabetes`) for ease (this is not my project data but concept should be the same). I would then like to do the preProcess only on a subset of variables i.e. PimaIndiansDiabetes[, c(4,5,6)]. Is there a way to do this?

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

control <- trainControl(method="cv", 
                        number=5)
p <- preProcess(PimaIndiansDiabetes[, c(4,5,6)], #only do these columns!
                     method = c("center", "scale", "pca"))
p
grid=expand.grid(mtry=c(1,2,3))

model <- train(diabetes~., data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, method="rf", 
               preProcess= p, 
               trControl=control,
               tuneGrid=grid)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: pre-processing methods are limited to: BoxCox, YeoJohnson, expoTrans, invHyperbolicSine, center, scale, range, knnImpute, bagImpute, medianImpute, pca, ica, spatialSign, ignore, keep, remove, zv, nzv, conditionalX, corr
```

The reason I'm trying to do this is so I can reduce three variables to one PCA1 and use for predicting. In the project I'm doing all three variables are correlated above 90% but would like to incorporate them as other studies have used them as well. Thanks. Trying to avoid data leakage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible with caret.
This might be possible using [recipes](https://tidymodels.github.io/recipes/). However I do not use recipes but I do use [mlr3](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3) so I will show how to do it with this package:

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3learners)
library(paradox)
library(mlr3tuning)
library(mlbench)
```

create a task from the data:

```
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes")

pima_tsk <- TaskClassif$new(id = "Pima",
                            backend = PimaIndiansDiabetes,
                            target = "diabetes")
```

define a pre process selector named "slct1":

```
pos1 <- po("select", id = "slct1")
```

and define the selector function within it:

```
pos1$param_set$values$selector <- selector_name(colnames(PimaIndiansDiabetes[, 4:6]))
```

now define what should happen to the selected features: scaling -> pca with 1st PC selected (`param_vals = list(rank. = 1)`)

```
pos1 %>>%
  po("scale", id = "scale1") %>>%
  po("pca", id = "pca1", param_vals = list(rank. = 1)) -> pr1
```

now define an invert selector:

```
pos2 <- po("select", id = "slct2")

pos2$param_set$values$selector <- selector_invert(pos1$param_set$values$selector)
```

define the learner:

```
rf_lrn <- po("learner", lrn("classif.ranger")) #ranger is a faster version of rf
```

combine them:

```
gunion(list(pr1, pos2)) %>>%
  po("featureunion") %>>%
  rf_lrn -> graph
```

check if it looks ok:

```
graph$plot(html = TRUE)
```

[image]

convert graph to a learner:

```
glrn <- GraphLearner$new(graph)
```

define parameters you want tuned:

```
ps <-  ParamSet$new(list(
  ParamInt$new("classif.ranger.mtry", lower = 1, upper = 6),
  ParamInt$new("classif.ranger.num.trees", lower = 100, upper = 1000)))
```

define resampling:

```
cv10 <- rsmp("cv", folds = 10)
```

define tuning:

```
instance <- TuningInstance$new(
  task = pima_tsk,
  learner = glrn,
  resampling = cv10,
  measures = msr("classif.ce"),
  param_set = ps,
  terminator = term("evals", n_evals = 20)
)

set.seed(1)
tuner <- TunerRandomSearch$new()
tuner$tune(instance)
instance$result
```

For additional details on how to tune the number of PC components to keep check this answer: [R caret: How do I apply separate pca to different dataframes before training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59452615/r-caret-how-do-i-apply-separate-pca-to-different-dataframes-before-training/59480195#59480195)

If you find this interesting check out the [mlr3book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/)

Also

```
cor(PimaIndiansDiabetes[, 4:6])
          triceps   insulin      mass
triceps 1.0000000 0.4367826 0.3925732
insulin 0.4367826 1.0000000 0.1978591
mass    0.3925732 0.1978591 1.0000000
```

does not produce what you mention in the question.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot, thanks! Also, the >90% was from the data i'm using in my project. Just used the PimaIndiansDiabetes data as an example since it was tied to the link and easier to use. However, thanks for pointing that out I'll edit so it's clear.

Comment: That is pretty sweet, going to look into mlr3 after this project is done. I’m digging it from what you’ve shown me.

Comment: Much more complex pipelines are also possible.